# ASP.NET MVC authentication using http header

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, http-headers

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 application I need to authenticate the user using an existing **http header value** which contains the username.

It works using form authentication : the user is redirected to a login page when he is not authenticated yet. The controller of the login page check the httpHeader value and connect the user using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username,false)` and redirect the user to the main page of my application.

But I want to avoid this redirection and directly try to authenticate the user when the event 'user not authenticated' is fired.

Axes :

- FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate
- Override AuthorizeAttribute
- AuthenticateRequest

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly then you just need to set currentPrincipal with username

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user, "Basic"),                                     new string[] {});
```

So from now it will work and you can access user as well User.Identity.Name